# Select only nodes of Boost ptree

Tags: c++, boost

Considering the following XML-file:

```
<debug>
    <modules group="0">
        <module>Finance</module>
        <module>Admin</module>
        <module>HR</module>
    </modules>
</debug>
```

With Boost.PropertyTree it is possible to iterate over the children of a node:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("debug.modules"))
{
}
```

But since an attribute is considered as a child too, the first child of "modules" would be "group" but not a "module".
Is there any way to select only child nodes of a property tree?
One possibility would be to check for

```
if(v.first == "module")
```

but is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`equal_range()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idp205799312-bb) member function on `property_tree`, which returns a `std::pair` of iterators marking a range of child nodes with a specific key. Then you can use [Boost Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) to operate on the range.

This works nicely with C++11's `auto` type specifier and range-based for loops (or `BOOST_AUTO` and `BOOST_FOREACH`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

static const std::string input =
   "<debug>"
   " <modules group=\"0\">"
   "  <module>Finance</module>"
   "  <module>Admin</module>"
   "  <module>HR</module>"
   " </modules>"
   "</debug>";

int main() {
   std::istringstream istream(input);
   boost::property_tree::ptree ptree;
   boost::property_tree::read_xml(istream, ptree);

   const auto range = ptree.get_child("debug.modules").equal_range("module");
   for (auto& child : boost::make_iterator_range(range)) {
      std::cout << child.first << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

[Demo on CoLiRu](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b588a262dcc8229)

This is algorithmically better than checking every child, though I doubt it makes much difference in ordinary usage.

Comment: Perfect. That is the solution I searched for. It works fine for me. Thanks!